# Generate synthetic random image with predefined randomness

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing, random

I am trying to generate circular image with two distinct colors. Currently, I can control the ratio of two colors but I want the ability to control the adjacency of the colors too. For example, if the randomness is high then the probability of getting two pixel of same color would be low. Below is my code to generate image so far:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class GenerateImage:
    def __init__(self, radius=24):
        self.radius = radius
        self.image = np.zeros(shape=(48, 48, 3))
        
    def generate_random(self, prob=[0.5, 0.5]):
        mask = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=np.prod(self.image.shape[:2]), p=prob)
        mask = mask.reshape(self.image.shape[:2])
        self.image[:, :, 1] = mask * 255
        self.image[:, :, 2] = np.where(mask == 1, 0, 1) * 255
        
        x, y = np.ogrid[0:self.image.shape[0], 0:self.image.shape[1]]
        center_x = self.image.shape[0] / 2 - 0.5
        center_y = self.image.shape[1] / 2 - 0.5
        circle_mask = (x - center_x)**2 + (y - center_y)**2 > self.radius**2
        self.image[circle_mask] = [0,0,0]
        
    
    def display(self):
        plt.imshow(self.image)
        self.generate_random()
        plt.show()
        
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    g = GenerateImage()
    g.generate_random(prob=[0.5, 0.5])
    g.display()
```

It produces images like:

[image]

There are linear patches of blue or green colors that I want to control. What would be a reasonable way to achieve that? Thanks.

Another question (if anyone knows): how to compute the entropy of a colored image (I can use skimage to find entropy of a grayscale image but couldn't find any resource to do that for colored images like the one above)

Comment: Regarding the entropy, if you treat each of the channels independently, you could just take the entropy of each channel, e.g. H(img[..., 0]) + H(img[..., 1]) + H(img[..., 2]). Food for thought :)

Comment: That's a great idea! I will definitely try it. Still it would be nice to try all three channels simultaneously.

Comment: @RyanSander that will not be the entropy of the signal. it's like saying the entropy of a list of numbers is the same as the sum of the entropies of lists of numbers that sum up to that list of numbers - which is completely wrong. there is correlation and association between the channles. Your signal is all of them put together not each of them by itself. You can compute the entropy of your image by considering each pixel (or combination of 3 channels) as a symbol. then compute the occurrence probability of each symbol in your data and use those probabilities to compute the entropy

Comment: as for "controling" your "random" image, you can use one of the noise synthesis methods emploid by dithering algorithms to create "noise" with your desired structure. You can read more about it on the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither)